# Getting Facebook username for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the following to get the Facebook username:

```
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:facebook];
```

from my understanding I then have to use something like the following request to

```
  - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

  NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
  NSDictionary *userInfo = (NSDictionary *)result;
  userName = [userInfo objectForKey:@"name"];
  fb_id = [userInfo objectForKey:@"id"];
  }
```

my question is how do I call this request method from another method?

thanks for any help

Comment: your question is not clear .. can you please explain with more details what you want exactly to do ?

Comment: for now I just want to NSLog the Facebook username to the console. and also how would I call the - (void)request: didLoad: method from viewDidLoad?

Comment: the userName for every friend .. or just the userName for the logged in user ??

Comment: just the user whose logged in. I'm trying that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check my function below to fetch user data id,pic and name

```
- (void)fetchUserDetails {
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid=me()", @"query",nil];

    [fb requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                                     andParams:params
                                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                   andDelegate:self];


}
```

and in the delegate method you will log the name like this

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result 
{
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [result count]>0) {
            result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
   }
   if ([result objectForKey:@"name"]) 
            NSString *userName = [result objectForKey:@"name"];

   NSLog(@"%@",userName);
}
```

Comment: thank you. can you answer me this?: if I have the method             - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {...} how do I call it from another method. Usually it's something like [self nameOfMethod]; from within viewDidLoad or something. thanks again

Comment: this is a delegate method its just fired when the Facebook request did load successfully , you should not call it .. anyway just tell me your need and why you are try to call this method ?

Comment: [fb requestWithMethodName
what class is fb??